# Statement not working in query whether it print right statement

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

When I simply echo $statement then it shows the right MySQL statement but not working in the query.
If I put that echo statement into query then it's working. But I need a dynamically change statement.

```
<script>
function aaa(reply){
var rep= reply;
document.cookie = "repname" + "=" + reply + ";" + 30 + ";path=/";
                }
</script>
                                            
<?php
if(!empty($_COOKIE['repname'])) {
$statement=$_COOKIE['repname'];
////echo $statement;
$query= mysqli_query($conn,$statement);
if($query){
            echo "Working"
                                                
        }else{
            echo "Not working$statement";
            } ?>
```

Comment: Does it drop an error? Could you show the query? Need more info please

Comment: Please show what echo $statement returns. Also please make sure you've got mysqli set up to throw exceptions when errors occur, and that you've got PHP set up to log exceptions and warnings. That way you will get some information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Just so that you're aware, if a user changes the cookie in the browser before accessing your page, they can most likely execute any SQL statement on your database, including dropping the whole database, deleting all table content or inserting their own data in any table.